# How can I prevent port number from being attached to url in nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, url, port-number

Consider the server name [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and the application should work on the port number 3000.

When I type [www.example.com/user](http://www.example.com/user) which is the proxied url for our user application received from the host team, the application does not work. It authomatically redirects from [www.example.com/user](http://www.example.com/user) to [www.example.com:3000/user/](http://www.example.com:3000/user/)

But When I type [www.example.com/user/](http://www.example.com/user/) with trailing slash at the end, the application works perfectly.

I want the application to work when typing [www.example.com/user](http://www.example.com/user) without redirecting to [www.example.com:3000/user/](http://www.example.com:3000/user/)

For that, it should not add :3000 anymore on the url and the application should work. Thank you for helping.

Here is my code:

```
worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 4096;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    sendfile on;

    server {
        listen 3000 ssl;
        listen [::]:3000 ssl;

        resolver 127.0.0.11;
        autoindex off;

        server_name dthhub.umadev.dth.ihost.com;
        server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/d2dnode02.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/d2dnode02.key;
        

        location /user {
            #alias /app/dist/dashboard-user;
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;
        }
        gzip_static on;
    } 

}
```

Comment: Not without any kind of configuration you have set. Please, provide the relevant code.

Comment: I added my nginx configuration. I already tested it with stuffs like proxy_pass, proxy_set_header etc but it did not work

Comment: You could try using a regex : location ~ ^/user(?:/(.*))?$ {
    alias //usr/share/nginx/html/$1;
}

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.